# MongoDB replica set setup issues

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, replicaset

I'm having extreme frustration trying to setup a MongoDB replica set from scratch.  This is my first run with MongoDB (2.4.6) and I'm not sure if it's my lack of comprehension or poor documentation.  Here's what I'm working with:

-Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 12.04 LTS instances in a VPC
-NodeA 10.0.1.152
-NodeB 10.0.1.153

They can communicate fine to each other.  These servers are fresh from scratch so no firewall rules.  My hosts files:

10.0.1.152 mongodb0
10.0.1.153 mongodb1
10.0.1.226 mongodb2 #this is arbiter, but I don't care about this at the moment

My conf in NodeA

```
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
fork = true
replSet = rs0
bind_ip = mongodb0
logappend=true
```

My conf in NodeB

```
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
fork = true
replSet = rs0
bind_ip = mongodb1
logappend=true
```

On NodeA, I start the process:

```
 mongod --host mongodb0.iin
 rs.initiate()
 rs.conf()
 rs.add("mongo1.iin:27017")
```

here is the error message:

```
{
        "errmsg" : "exception: need most members up to reconfigure, not ok : mongodb1.iin:27017",
        "code" : 13144,
        "ok" : 0
}
```

I also ran the mongo process on the replica.  When I initialize, it is calling itself the Primary as well.

On NodeB - I ran a TCPDUMP on all traffic from NodeA.  When I intialize - nothing shows up. As I've mentioned there's no firewall rules and I even added to allow everything from NodeA just for the sake of it.

**WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?!?!?!?!?!?**

Comment: so, first you started NodeA??

Comment: By the explanation you gave:
1: if you use config file give it to mongod with the -f parameter like mongod -f nodeA.cfg.
2: You started the nodeA and tried to connect to nodeB which i assume still not running. Check this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-configuration/ documentation how to config a replicaset properly and also config consistently the hostname of the instances (mongodb0/monodb0.iin) use

Comment: In particular, make sure that the hostnames don't evaluate to `127.0.0.1` or `::1`. If the listening socket is bound to the loopback adapter, *nothing* from the outside will be able to connect to it.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look at the environment, but I'm thinking it may be network related and need to evaluate that.  I'd like to verify that in each config on NodeA and NodeB, the replSet values should be the same?  I start and initiate NodeA, do i only start the process on NodeB (with no rs.initiate())?  When I add NodeB to NodeA, is that the formal process?

Comment: Please post `mongodb.log` here

Answer (score 0):

1) make sure the host->ip name is available in /etc/hosts file in each server.

for example your /etc/hosts file
having

```
123.123.123.123 hostname
```

I am assuming 123.123.123.123 is your server ip and hostname is the name you have given to mongo replica set member for each and every member you have to do this and for each server you have to add this.

2) make sure mongo nodes are able to communicate with each other using terminal you can test this.

3) make sure your system is able to communicate with each member of replica set from where you are accessing the members.( mongod.conf file basically)